# Angular test cases mocking controller as value

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, testcase

I am stuck in writing test cases of angular directive. I am injecting my controller in test and i am able to stub `$scope` value but i am not able to stub `this` value of controller, which is giving me undefined and test case not passing. I have following angular controller:

```
export default class myCtrl {
    constructor($rootScope, $ngRedux, $scope) {
        const unsubscribe = $ngRedux.connect(this.mapStateToThis, bodyActions)(this);
        $scope.$on('$destroy', unsubscribe);
        const step = this;

        step.buttonClassName = 'sBtn';
        step.appState.selectedService = step.appState.selectedService || '';
        console.log(step.customFunction());

    }
    customFunction() {
        return 'test';
    }
     mapStateToThis(state) {
        return {
            appState: state.app
        };
    }
}
```

This is following test case code:

```
describe('directive test case', function () {
    var $scope,
        $controller,
        compile,
        directiveElem,
        innerScope,
        element,
        compiledElement,
        state, step;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope, $controller, $state, _$httpBackend_, $q) {    inject arguments of given function
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_
        state = $state
        compile = $compile
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $scope.test = {};
        $httpBackend.when('GET', 'languages/locale-en.json').respond(languageEng);
        console.log(myCtrl);
        step = $controller(myCtrl, {$scope: $scope, test: 'test'});  // Problem is here
    }
}
```

As you can see i am using `controller as` syntax. So `step` having `this` value. I am not able to set default test value for `step.appState` or mock it.

How can I stub/mock step's functions and variables from test?

Any suggestions?

Comment: What **exactly** is the error? The undefined value could be `bodyActions`. Where is that supposed to come from?

Comment: @Phil I have updated my question. Exact problem is i am not able to mock/stub `customFunction` from test.

Comment: You shouldn't be mocking / stubbing a method of your test candidate

Comment: @Phil in `step.appState` i am getting default value of reducer which is `null`. So where ever i have used `step.appState.userId` i am getting error `userId` of null. So can i mock/stub `appState` value from test?